# react native returning network error when made get request to my django server [ which is running live on server and not on localhost ]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I tried other public api's and they worked but when I try my own GET api created in django rest framework it returns network error.

Note : I have my server running on digital ocean to which I am making request using axios.get() and not to local server.

also I have added in settings.py

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

and when I run the same api's in postman or directly on browser they successfully returns the data, so the problem is with react native code can someone help in guiding where I am wrong.

below the example of my code.

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const {data} = await axios.get('https://myGETurl/');
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  };
```

Comment: most of the time, axios throws "network error" commonly, even if there is an error in  payload. So first check ur internet connection is connected, and then make sure your api  "https" enabled. and are you trying it with real device or emulator?

Comment: i am trying with an emulator, and yes i have an active internet connection, also those same api returns the data in postman....

Comment: even other github public testing apis are working , its just my apis who aren't in axios only.

Comment: yeah. actually your api in http you have to some custom changes in your emulator. if it is 'Https' then its ok. thats why asked about it.

Comment: since you mentioned that its not working with axios only, have you tried it with fetch?

Comment: @Manojkanth no brother, it is not working, do you know any other option

Comment: just see this answers. it may help you https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/973

Comment: i read that issue and tried those ways but didn't work for me